# Have an error in hasManyThrough

Tags: laravel, relation

I have problem when use hasManyThrough in Laravel .
my tables :

[image]

In the Branch model I have this

```
public function works()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Work', 'App\Field','branch_id','field_id');
}
```

and in route I have this

```
$b= App\Branch::all()->first();
dd($b->works()->get());
```

and get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fields.branch_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `works`.*, `fields`.`branch_id` from `works` inner join `fields` on `fields`.`id` = `works`.`field_id` where `fields`.`branch_id` = 1)
```

Comment: what are u trying to achieve ?

Comment: @jaysingkar trying to get the works of one branch

Comment: It's not possible to use `hasManyThrough()` in many to many relationship. Though you can achieve this by few methods as given in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any provision for using `hasManyThrough()` in many-to-many relation. But you can achieve this by using either `DB::raw()` or you can add following function to your BaseModel as given in this [forum](http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many).

```
public function manyThroughMany($related, $through, $firstKey, $secondKey, $pivotKey)
   {
       $model = new $related;
       $table = $model->getTable();
       $throughModel = new $through;
       $pivot = $throughModel->getTable();

       return $model
           ->join($pivot, $pivot . '.' . $pivotKey, '=', $table . '.' . $secondKey)
           ->select($table . '.*')
           ->where($pivot . '.' . $firstKey, '=', $this->id);
   }
```